# Stairs on normal map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, normal-map

I try to bake a normal map usin cycles render but have a strange artifacts. It's look like a stairs on output image.
How can i fix it ? 
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (at least a part of it)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/